# When using a .rpm file, will that need to be repeated?

Tags: rpm, file-extension

When utilizing a .rpm file, I'm assuming this only needs to happen once since it is an installation file. A .rpm file is an installation package for Linux systems. Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The RPM Package Manager (RPM) is a powerful package management system capable of

1. building computer software from the source into easily distributable packages
2. installing, updating and uninstalling packaged software
3. querying detailed information about the packaged software, whether installed or not
4. verifying the integrity of packaged software and resulting software installation

Source [rpm.org](https://rpm.org/)